# gwtboostrap3 12 columns grid

Tags: java, gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to use a 12-columns grid system from `GWTBootstrap3` in my `GWT` project. The following snippet is from `UI Binder`:

```
<row>
<column size="1">1</column>
<column size="1">2</column>
....
<column size="1">12</column>
</row>
```

I expected to see one line with 12 cells with text: 
`1 2 3 ....11 12`
But I got 12 rows one under other:
1
2
...
12

My question - is there 12-columns grid system in `gwt-bootstrap3` ? and if so
I do not see it in `gwt-bootstrap3` demo and others official examples, but I found this code in examples for `bootstrap` (not `getbootstrap3`).

Comment: Yes, as [documentation](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#gridSystem) states.

Comment: Thanks! I can't find the doc on front page menu. I will try this.

Comment: Did you wrap your grid rows in a <div class="container"> ...  </div> , as required by bootstrap?